# waitForElement Not JSON Response, when trying to access button element

Tags: appium, nativescript, e2e-testing

First of all, I'm quite new to NativeScript and e2e testing, but I'm trying to get some simple tests to run on my demo application. I did the whole setup where I installed everything and an e2e (default) folder + files were created.

I have this demo app layout where I basically have one button:

```
<ActionBar title="My App" class="action-bar">
</ActionBar>

<GridLayout class="page">
     <StackLayout>
        <Button automationText="testButton" text="Button"></Button>
     </StackLayout>
</GridLayout>
```

These are my tests:

```
import { AppiumDriver, createDriver, SearchOptions } from "nativescript-dev-appium";
import { assert } from "chai";

describe("sample scenario", () => {
    const defaultWaitTime = 5000;
    let driver: AppiumDriver;

    before(async () => {
        driver = await createDriver();
    });

    after(async () => {
        await driver.quit();
        console.log("Quit driver!");
    });

    afterEach(async function () {
        if (this.currentTest.state === "failed") {
           // await driver.logTestArtifacts(this.currentTest.title);
        }
    });

    it("should find an element by text", async () => {
        const btn = await driver.findElementByText("Button");
        assert.isTrue(btn.exists());
    });

    it("should find an element by automation text", async () => {
         const btn = await driver.findElementByAutomationText("testButton");
         assert.isTrue(btn.exists());
    });
});
```

I had to comment this line, otherwise, my tests wouldn't finish (I had to manually stop them with ctrl C):

```
// await driver.logTestArtifacts(this.currentTest.title);
```

I am running it with:

```
$ npm build ios
$ npm run e2e -- --runType sim.iPhone6
```

I am able to run stupid tests, assertTrue(true), but when I am trying to access an element, the button, things go wrong:

```
    should find an element by text:
 [waitForElementByXPath("//*[@label='Button' or @value='Button' or @hint='Button']",5000)] [elements("xpath","//*[@label='Button' or @value='Button' or @hint='Button']")] Not JSON response
  Error: [elements("xpath","//*[@label='Button' or @value='Button' or @hint='Button']")] Not JSON response
  at exports.newError (node_modules/wd/lib/utils.js:151:13)
```

And:

```
 should find an element by automation text:
 [waitForElementByAccessibilityId("testButton",5000)] [elements("accessibility id","testButton")] Not JSON response
  Error: [elements("accessibility id","testButton")] Not JSON response
  at exports.newError (node_modules/wd/lib/utils.js:151:13)
```

I also tried to see if the driver was just empty or something like that, but isIOS and isAndroid work fine.

I don't know if this has something do to with it but when killing the driver this error also pops up:

```
Error: [quit()] Unexpected data in simpleCallback.
```

If anybody could help that would be great! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a similar issue logged in at the [{N} Appium Github repo](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-dev-appium/issues/137), the problem seems to be the environment setup, at least in their case it was not installing `carthage`.

Did you go through the [setup process here](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-dev-appium/blob/master/README.md#setup), made sure you have everything in place?

Comment: I found that issue as well, but brew install carthage just tells me it is already installed.

Comment: I also did run all the setup commands again to check if I missed anything, but everything was already installed.